# How to hide Out[] cells in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

After executing a cell which becomes the `In[x]` cell, I see an `Out[x]` cell immediately even if there is no output. How can I configure Jupyter notebook to hide these `Out[x]` cells and only print the console output from a print statement?

Answer (score 3):

You can add a semicolon in you in-cell.

With output:

```
In [1]: 1
Out[1]: 1
```

Without output:

```
In[1]: 1;
```

The trailing semicolon ends the line and adds a new, empty line, that has no visible output.

Comment: Nice! I never knew this!  Do you know if this is by design? It doesn't work like this in a normal repl...

Comment: Hi Mike, I tried placing a semicolon at the end of the expression but I still see an empty line which says,

In[1]: 1;
Out[1]: <empty line>

Comment: What browser are you using?